# repl node js problem SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

- I am trying to learn node js.
- so I used the below example and implemented in repl.
  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2
- but I am not able to run the app.
- when I run the app I am getting the below error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code base below.
- is there any online editor where I can run node js and see

https://repl.it/@doadhdoadh/IdleAccurateSource

```
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const port = 8000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});



node v9.7.1 linux/amd64
   npm dev
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
npm dev
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:181:10)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at fs.read (fs.js:2124:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the original `server.js` file and found that you were missing a semicolon on line 12 i.e `db = database.db("api");`

> Update

I just realised that the repl NodeJs demo gets triggered using index.js file. I just exported a function in server.js and imported it in index.js to trigger the server creation process.

Check [the updated poc](https://repl.it/@ManojChalode/node-demo)

Hope it works!

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but when I run npm dev in the terminal I still see error, can you tellme how to fix it

Comment: can you try `npm run dev`? the `package.json` scripts are run using `npm run script_name` command.

Comment: hey still I am seeing this error unexpected identifier...can you run it in repl terminal

Comment: any idea can you help me

Comment: It seems the repl NodeJs app gets triggered with `index.js` file. check the updated project. I am still trying to figure out how to use `nodemon` though..

Comment: hey thanks for yourresearch but still I am not able to run

Comment: What error are you getting? Obviously, mongo connection will fail as the POC has invalid mongo URL.

Comment: hey did you try with valid mongo connection

Comment: You will have to try that mate, I can't put a valid mongo connection in a POC :)